# Computing the basis of a subspace of matrices with the given nullspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Compute the dimension and find a basis for the subspace of matrices $H ⊂ M_{3×5} (\mathbb{R})$
such that $[0,2,−3,0,1]^T$ is in the nullspace of A ∈ H.

I have said that, if we want $[0,2,−3,0,1]^T$ to be in the nullspace of A, then we must be able to write,

$$c_1\vec{v_1}+...+c_k\vec{v_k} = [0,2,−3,0,1]^T $$

where $S = \{\vec{v_1},...,\vec{v_k}\}$ is a basis for the nullspace of A.

so we require

$$V\mathbb{\vec{c}} =  [0,2,−3,0,1]^T $$ to be consistent. where $V$ is a matrix whose columns are the elements of S.

How can I move on from here?

**I feel as though this is wrong in the first place. Could someone give me push please.**

Comment: Why not try finding the general form of a $3\times 5$ matrix whose nullspace contains that element?  Then you might be able to write down a basis for $H$. To find the general form, let the entries of $A$ be $(a_{ij})$ and compute $A$ times the given vector so that you can see what equations the $a_{ij}$ must satisfy.

Comment: I am kicking myself, If the vector is in the null space of A then it is a solution of $Ax = 0$, by definition! Now I have done what you suggested and obtained $ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2a_{12} & -3a_{13} & a_{15} \\
2a_{22} & -3a_{23} &  a_{25}  \\
2a_{32} & -3{a_33} &  a_{35} \end{array} \right)$ I don't see it at the moment.

Comment: Your matrix multiplication isn't quite right.  $A$ is $3\times 5$ so $Av$, where $v$ is the given vector, is a height three column vector which you want to be zero if $A \in H$ (it's the sum of the rows of the 3x3 matrix you wrote down). That gives some equations the $a_{ij}$ satisfy.

Comment: It is a column vector, just I forgot to add the addition signs in. According to the equations.  I obtain $2a_{12} = 3a_{13} - a_{15}$, so if I am understanding this correctly, the first row of $A$  could be $(1,1,1,1,1)$, since there are no restrictions on the other elements also. I think I need to come back to this. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: You're right that the first row of $A$ *could* be that, but you need to find all possible $A$. What you should take from your equations is that $A$ is in $H$ iff $a_{i5}=3a_{i3}-2a_{i2}$ for all $i=1,2,3$.  So every entry of $A$ except $a_{15},a_{25}a_{35}$ can be chosen freely and then those elements are determined by the choices you have made.  This helps you find a basis and the dimension.

Comment: Re: *This type of post must be on here* (you wrote in your meta post). You can try to look at some of these posts: [given nullspace site:math.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=given+nullspace+site:math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi there _mt, I have posted a solution which seems to satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simpler case where you want a basis for the space $H$ of 2x3 matrices $A=(a_{ij})$ such that $2a_{i2}-a_{i3}=0$.  Then a general matrix in $H$ looks like
$$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc} a &b&2b \\ c &d & 2d \end{array}\right)$$
This equals 
$$ a \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 &0&0 \\ 0 &0 & 0 \end{array}\right) + b \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 &1&2 \\ 0 &0 & 0 \end{array}\right)+ c \left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 &0&0 \\ 1 &0 & 0 \end{array}\right)+d\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 0 &0&0 \\ 0 &1 & 2 \end{array}\right)$$
and all of the four matrices above are in $H$.  Therefore they are a spanning set for $H$.  You can also see that they are linearly independent: if the expression above equals the zero matrix then $a=0$ (look at the top left corner), $b=0$ (the 1,2 entry), and so on.  Thus they are a basis of $H$, and it has dimension 4.

Your problem is similar but a bit harder, nevertheless you can do it a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

$$\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 5\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 5\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 &0 & 5\end{array} \right)\}$$

so $Dim(H) =6$

Comment: This set satisfies the conditions and is linearly independent. The restriction is satisfied in all the matrices and since there is no restriction on the other entries we can have them whatever we like. if we add two of the matrices together we still have the condition satisfied... I hope.

Comment: This is better because the matrices now are in $H$. But it isn't a basis (the dimension is 12).

Comment: Is this because of the ones? for example in the first matrix, the second row has a one in the first entry? I thought  because there is no restriction on these entries that we can choose them as we wish.

Comment: I don't understand "because of the ones." You are trying to write down a basis.  This means that in particular it has to be a spanning set, but this set doesn't span $H$. It can't do because $\dim H = 12$.  I will write an answer in a moment.

Comment: I am sorry, I am finding this question beyond difficult. Perhaps the answer might make it clear where I am going wrong. Thanks.